# Selenium IsElementPresent does not work in IE

Tags: javascript, selenium

I am making use of selenium for some testing and although this works when I launch firefox using selenium. It fails in IE. I get a command execution failure and I when I catch the exception, its a `Permission Denied`?

```
while (selenium.IsElementPresent(element) == false){

   // wait

}
```

Any ideas why?

Maybe I can achieve the same thing using some javascript function to test if an element is present with a combination of xpath and css parameters, just the way `IsElementPresent` works?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Internet Explorer is picky about the state of the page when you try to check for things on it.  You're probably not waiting for the page to be fully-loaded (via `WaitForPageToLoad()`) before calling `IsElementPresent()`.  That's the single largest source of IE "permission denied" errors - performing commands while the page is still loading.